# How to display a simple monthly calendar

Tags: java, android

I am building an Android app and I need to show a very simple monthly calendar (with next and previous month links). And, if possible, display events on some days.

I have search, high and low, for a solution but found nothing.
Isn´t there a very simple way of doing this? All the widgets I find got too much features.

Comment: Android does not have much in the way of printing support before Android 4.4.

Comment: Sorry, when I say print, I mean showing a calendar in an activity.

Comment: There is a calendar item which you can drag-and-drop onto your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library:
https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers

I currently use it to show a monthly calendar. it looks good, clean and is extremely easy to implement in an application.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps but maybe consider using a `DatePickerDialog` and put it into a `DialogFragment`, while making sure to use the `CalendarView`... all of which is native to the Android SDK so it's a piece of cake to implement.

Also I have heard of a GitHub Library available called DateTimePicker, you can find more information here https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker ... it might be a little harder to configure for your exact needs but it's probably worth a look.